# google OAuth2 getting access token for service account: connect timed out

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-api, dialogflow-es, google-oauth

I'm working on a server-to-server interactions with Google DialogFlow APIs on behalf of the service account by using google OAuth2.
But I get the error when try to generate the access token(credentials.refreshIfExpired()):

`java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: connect timed out`

[image]

here the codes:

```
    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(System.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")));

    if (credentials.createScopedRequired()) {
        credentials = credentials.createScoped(Collections.singletonList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dialogflow"));
    }

    credentials.refreshIfExpired();
    AccessToken token = credentials.getAccessToken();

    System.out.println(token.getTokenValue());
```

I have tried to find the solution in many ways, and someone said that it may cause of the synchronization between my server time and google's time.

Then I set default timeZone in GMT

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DialogFlowDemoApplication {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        System.out.println("Spring boot application running in GMT timezone :"+new Date());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(DialogFlowDemoApplication.class, args);

    }
}
```

[image]

But it doesn't help, that really drives me crazy.

my dependencies as follow:

```
<!--start google dependencies-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-dialogflow</artifactId>
    <version>0.108.0-alpha</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.30.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
    <version>1.90.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.30.4</version>
</dependency>
<!--end of google dependencies-->
```

**Please help, thanks!**

Comment: Is this working in local? Sounds like your server firewall stopping egress traffic

Comment: Yes I run it in local. I just turn off the firewall but it still throws that error :(

Comment: `curl -I "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"` see if this works in your server

Comment: em... "Failed to connect to oauth2.googleapis.com port 443: Timed out"

Comment: but if I use postman to generate the access token in OAuth2 with the access token url `"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"` , it works. what are the differences between them

Comment: Your local postman has good access to outside world network, but your server still behind firewall, not sure you have ufw or some network level firewall from your cloud/server provider.

Answer (score 0):

This was internet connectivity issue in my case. I routed the request via an HTTP PROXY and it worked fine. JVM options for java:

```
-Dhttps.proxyHost=10.128.0.3
-Dhttps.proxyPort=3128
```